# What's the max influence gain in Stellaris per faction per month?

Tags: stellaris

In Stellaris, you can research the tech The Collective Self, which gives "+1 Max influence from factions [per month]."

But as much as I struggle and google, I cannot find out what the max is with or without this tech.

In my game, I am getting +3.5 monthly influence from Egalitarians and +2.4 influence from Xenophiles; but what is the max?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The influence that a happy (60%+) faction gives depends on its support. A faction with 100% support will generate the maximum amount of influence. A faction with less generates a percentage of the max equal to its support. Support is defined as the percentage of pops supporting a faction.

In this case, the Free Citizen Centre is generating 54% of the max influence, while the Xeno Protection Council is generating 38%. The fact that they're even happier doesn't change anything- all that matters is that it's at least 60%.

The initial max influence from factions is 2, but this can be increased by various methods, such as:

- Society Technologies, such as The Living State chain
- Egalitarian Ethics
- Civics, such as Parliamentary State

Comment: This does seem to make sense based on how long I've played.  Thank you!  Wish that was more clear, the politics-sim part of this game is amazing.